# Minimum value of plt.pause()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib's pause function.

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pause.html

What is the range of the value which is acceptable in the pause function?

Answer (score 1):

## [ 0.01000...00001 seconds ] minimum value

This is what i found..

```
plt.pause(interval=timeout)
```

calls to:

```
def start_event_loop(timeout):
  if timeout <= 0: timeout = np.inf
  timestep = 0.01
  counter = 0
  self._looping = True
  while self._looping and counter * timestep < timeout:
    self.flush_events()
    time.sleep(timestep)
    counter += 1
```

wich calls time.sleep at intervals of 0.01 sec.

If you want faster try this:

[Faster rendering by using blitting](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/tutorials/advanced/blitting.html)